# Как вывести background video on WordPress без плагина

Tags: css, wordpress, css3, html5, background

Уважаемые профессионалы своего дела. У меня есть проблемка: появилась задача вставить background video в шаблон на WordPress, который совместно работает с WooCommerce. Какие я плагины и редакторы не пробовал - вроде elementos, page builder and visual composer, результат один - у темы только область контента задается видео, а именно, сам background не меняется, он остается белым.А мне нужно задать именно фон, чтобы белый фон стал видео, а область контента осталась неизменой.

У кого какие мысли по поводу подключения mp4 видео в фон сайта на WordPress + WooCommerce без плагина?

Comment: Можно сделать и без с плагинов, и с ними. Вот это сделано на twentyseventeen и visual composer: polati.ru. Если не разберётесь, как сделано, покажите свою вёрстку html и css в вопросе.

Comment: Вот пример сайта https://water.tabsgame.com/